# Get info from my router VIA SSH CLI from a php page

Tags: php, ssh, command-line-interface

All,

I'm fairly new to php (simple forms and hello world stuff)

I'm trying to create a page that when loaded will go out grab some text information from a SSH session on my router parse it out and display it

The general idea would be

connect to (ip address, port)
send line (loginuser + Password)
send line (su to root + password)
send line (command)
receive text from command (string X)

parse x and display stats as html on page

I've seen a few tutorials on how to install libraries from ubuntu but my host is godaddy so i wont have access to install anything in that manner (i only have simple ftp access)

I'm looking for a simple simple simple ssh client and hopefully a small example on how to use it (send commands and retrieve text)

Thanks if you can help

Answer (score 2):

Ok, just for learning purposes, you can shell_exec on your box to connect to remote host with ssh, run a command and return response, evaluate and make some nice stats:

shell_exec("ssh user@yourhost.com run_your_command");
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

I would use phpseclib (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), a pure PHP SSH implementation, or if is available on your host use SSH2 extension. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

Comment: that looks like what im after, how do you specifiy the port ( I changed it for security) yourhost.com:4654654

Comment: for shell_exec: you can specify port as of an argument for ssh command itself: ssh -p4545 yourhost.com

Comment: how do you pass the password and how do you SU to root?

Comment: For phpseclib you can do new Net_SSH('hostname', portnum). To string commands together...  you could do $ssh->exec('...') multiple times. I'm not sure about su but here's how sudo would work: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#sudo I imagine su would be similar.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, im using <?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?> from the example I'm going to tweak it for a bit

Comment: The code works but i can't figure out how to su to root? any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not the right tool in my opinion, you can achieve better results with expect and some bash stuff.

[expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) is a good tool for command line activities. [Try to have a look](http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html)

Comment: How would i run this from my host?

Comment: Just create a bash script.

Comment: how would i run a bash script from a web host?

Comment: Depends. Some webhosts allow them, others not. BTW you didn't specify it in your question.

Comment: sorry I thought godaddy was specific enough (also asking for php) but thanks for the idea